# Liquidity - Unhandled exception (Invalid_argument List.fold_left2)

Tags: liquidity

My smart contract compiles but when I use any of the entry methods it throws "Unhandled exception (Invalid_argument List.fold_left2)". It seems to have happened when I added the owner parameter into the storage init.

```
type storage = {
  something: (address, nat list) map;
  is_on: bool;
  owner: address;
}

let%init storage (owner: address) =
  {
    something = Map [];
    is_on = true;
    owner;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you open an issue on https://github.com/OCamlPro/liquidity/issues ? Also can you provide a full example to reproduce the problem?
What do you mean by "when I use any of the entry methods"? Are you trying to call a deployed instance of the contract, or are you using the simulation feature of Liquidity? Are you using the command line compiler of the online interface?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your code in **Chrome private window**. 
This way helped solve the same issue for me.